# facebook marketing api code doesn't run correctly on compute engine

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to run some python code on my compute engine to pull a report from the facebook marketing api on a daily basis.

I have currently got the api set up to pull all ad id's for the ad account and they come through in facebook's weird format:

```
[<Ad> {
    "id": "23845614332840309"
}, <Ad> {
    "id": "23845614435580309"
}, <Ad> {
    "id": "23845614435590309"
},
...
```

so I am trying to get a list of id without the rest of the formating and I am using the following code:

```
test2 = [i for i in facebook_ad_ids]
test4 = []
for i in range(len(test2)):
    test4.append(str(test2[i]))

in2 = []
for i in range(len(test4)):
    in2.append(int(re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', test4[i])[0]))
```

This code works perfectly fine on my own computer, but when I upload to compute engine I get the error:

```
File "upload_test.py", line 30, in <listcomp>
test2 = [i for i in facebook_campaign_ids]
File "/home/name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/facebook_business/api.py", line 783, in __next__
if not self._queue and not self.load_next_page():
File "/home/name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/facebook_business/api.py", line 833, in load_next_page

self.params['summary'] = True
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Hey, the Error message tells you that there is something wrong on the line _self.params['summary'] = True_ It seems that it is a list (this is why it is expecting Integer indices) instead of a dictionary (whose elements are called with Strings). Could you please share the full code? This will give us more vision about the issue and will help us to help you better :)

Answer (score 0):

fixed my problem here by switching from Ubuntu 20.04 to Debian / Linux 9 on my compute engine